# autodiff for max()

Tags: python, jax, hessian-matrix, autodiff

I am doing optimization using maximum likelihood estimation, and when I am trying to get the standard errors of estimates using hessian matrix, I get non-invertible/singular hessian warning.

After I inspect the hessian, I find that there is a column/row of all zeros. What does this tell me? Should I worry about identifiability of my model?

```
jac [ 1.19782970e+00 -4.47698715e+01  1.07446142e+01 -0.00000000e+00
 -0.00000000e+00  1.49231202e-07 -0.00000000e+00  1.07650748e-08]
hes = jnp.outer(jac, jac) 
[[ 1.43479598e+00 -5.36266815e+01  1.28702180e+01 -0.00000000e+00
  -0.00000000e+00  1.78753565e-07 -0.00000000e+00  1.28947263e-08]
 [-5.36266815e+01  2.00434139e+03 -4.81034997e+02  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 -6.68106171e-06  0.00000000e+00 -4.81951017e-07]
 [ 1.28702180e+01 -4.81034997e+02  1.15446735e+02 -0.00000000e+00
  -0.00000000e+00  1.60343169e-06 -0.00000000e+00  1.15666576e-07]
 [-0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]
 [-0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.78753565e-07 -6.68106171e-06  1.60343169e-06 -0.00000000e+00
  -0.00000000e+00  2.22699515e-14 -0.00000000e+00  1.60648505e-15]
 [-0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.28947263e-08 -4.81951017e-07  1.15666576e-07 -0.00000000e+00
  -0.00000000e+00  1.60648505e-15 -0.00000000e+00  1.15886836e-16]]
```

I also have read in the posts that singularity might be caused by precision error, and add 
will fix the problem. But how can I figure it out if my problem is caused by precision in python (I am using float64, and autodifferentiation from jax for hessian)?

Code for reproduce:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)

class Model:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_p_l0(self,phi,id,time):
        df=self.data
        subdf = df[(df[:,0]==id)&(df[:,1]>=1)&(df[:,1]<=time)]

        weights=jnp.array([phi ** i for i in range(0, int(time))])[::-1]
        dem = weights.sum()

        nom1 = (weights * subdf[:,2]).sum()
        nom2 = (weights * subdf[:,3]).sum()
        nom3 = (weights * subdf[:,4]).sum()
        b1 = nom1 / dem
        b2 = nom2 / dem
        b3 = nom3 / dem

        a1,a2,a3 = self.get_attraction(b1, b2, b3)
        return [a1,a2,a3]

    def get_attraction(self, belief1, belief2, belief3):
        a1=20 * belief1 + 12 * belief2 + 6 * belief3
        a2=12 * belief1 + 24 * belief2 + 18 * belief3
        a3 = 23 * belief1 + 0 * belief2 + 40 * belief3
        return a1,a2,a3

    def get_prob(self, a1, a2, a3, lamda):
        m1 = lamda * a1
        m2 = lamda * a2
        m3 = lamda * a3

        m=jnp.array([m1,m2,m3]).T
        c=jnp.amax(m,axis=1)
        aa1 = jnp.exp(m1-c)
        aa2 = jnp.exp(m2-c)
        aa3 = jnp.exp(m3-c)
        logsumexp = c+jnp.log(jnp.array([aa1,aa2,aa3]).sum(axis=0))
        p1_ = jnp.exp(m1-logsumexp)
        p2_ = jnp.exp(m2-logsumexp)
        p3_ = jnp.exp(m3-logsumexp)

        return p1_, p2_, p3_

    def get_sub_prob(self,attractions):
        m = max(attractions)
        m_actions=[i+1 for i, j in enumerate(attractions) if j == m]

        if m_actions==[1]:
            p1_l1_l0,p2_l1_l0,p3_l1_l0 = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
        elif m_actions==[2] or m_actions==[1,2]:
            p1_l1_l0, p2_l1_l0, p3_l1_l0 = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
        else:
            p1_l1_l0, p2_l1_l0, p3_l1_l0 = 0.0, 0.0, 1.0

        return p1_l1_l0, p2_l1_l0, p3_l1_l0

    def get_prob_t_l1(self,p_hat,p1_l1_l0, p2_l1_l0, p3_l1_l0,):
        b1_t_a1 = p_hat+(1-p_hat)*p1_l1_l0
        b2_t_a1 = (1 - p_hat) * p2_l1_l0
        b3_t_a1 = (1 - p_hat) * p3_l1_l0

        a1_t_a1,a2_t_a1,a3_t_a1 = self.get_attraction(b1_t_a1,b2_t_a1,b3_t_a1)

        b1_t_a2 = (1 - p_hat) * p1_l1_l0
        b2_t_a2 = p_hat + (1 - p_hat) * p2_l1_l0
        b3_t_a2 = (1 - p_hat) * p3_l1_l0

        a1_t_a2, a2_t_a2, a3_t_a2 = self.get_attraction(b1_t_a2, b2_t_a2, b3_t_a2)

        b1_t_a3 = (1 - p_hat) * p1_l1_l0
        b2_t_a3 = (1 - p_hat) * p2_l1_l0
        b3_t_a3 = p_hat + (1 - p_hat) * p3_l1_l0

        a1_t_a3, a2_t_a3, a3_t_a3 = self.get_attraction(b1_t_a3, b2_t_a3, b3_t_a3)

        return a1_t_a1, a2_t_a2, a3_t_a3

    def get_l1_p_t_id(self, id, phi_hat, time):
        p_hat = 0.5

        a_l1_l0 = self.get_p_l0(phi=phi_hat, id=id, time=time)
        p1_l1_l0, p2_l1_l0, p3_l1_l0 = self.get_sub_prob(a_l1_l0)

        eu1, eu2, eu3 = self.get_prob_t_l1(p_hat,p1_l1_l0, p2_l1_l0, p3_l1_l0)

        return [eu1, eu2, eu3]

    def likelihood(self, params):
        p1 = params[0]
        lamda = params[1]
        phi = params[2]
        phi_hat = params[3]
        #k = params[4]

        df=self.data

        num_cores=1
        a_t_l0 = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(
            delayed(self.get_p_l0)(id=row[0], time=row[1], phi=phi) for row in df)

        a_t_l0=jnp.array(a_t_l0)
        p1_bl, p2_bl, p3_bl = self.get_prob(a_t_l0[:,0], a_t_l0[:,1], a_t_l0[:,2], lamda)

        a_t_l1 = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(self.get_l1_p_t_id)(id=row[0], time=row[1],phi_hat=phi_hat
                                                                        ) for row in df)
        a_t_l1=jnp.array(a_t_l1)
        p1_l1_t, p2_l1_t, p3_l1_t = self.get_prob(a_t_l1[:,0], a_t_l1[:,1], a_t_l1[:,2], lamda)

        f_l0 = p1_bl * df[:,5] + p2_bl * df[:,6] + p3_bl * df[:,7]
        f_l1 = p1_l1_t * df[:,5] + p2_l1_t * df[:,6] + p3_l1_t * df[:,7]

        num_ids = jnp.unique(df[:,0]).shape[0]
        ff_l0 = jnp.array([jnp.prod(i) for i in jnp.split(f_l0,num_ids)])
        ff_l1 = jnp.array([jnp.prod(i) for i in jnp.split(f_l1,num_ids)])

        pp = (1-p1) * ff_l0 + p1 * ff_l1

        li = jnp.log(pp)
        ll = jnp.sum(li)

        return -ll

    def get_se(self, params):
        hes = jax.hessian(self.likelihood)(params)
        print("hes",hes,)
        inv_hessian = jnp.linalg.inv(hes)
        print("inv",inv_hessian)
        diag_inv_hessian = jnp.diag(inv_hessian)
        print("diag",diag_inv_hessian)
        se = jnp.sqrt(diag_inv_hessian)
        return se

    def test(self, x0):
        print(self.likelihood(x0))

from jax import random
key = random.PRNGKey(1)
id = jnp.append(jnp.ones((100,)), jnp.ones((100,))*2)
choice = random.randint(key,(200,),1,4)
y1 = jnp.where(choice==1, 1, 0)
y2 = jnp.where(choice==2, 1, 0)
y3 = jnp.where(choice==3, 1, 0)
s = random.dirichlet(key, alpha=jnp.ones((3,)), shape=(200,), dtype=jnp.float64)
period=jnp.array([jnp.arange(1, 101)]*2).flatten()
data=jnp.column_stack((id,period,s,y1,y2,y3))


# Test
x0 = jnp.array([ 0.8,  2.745e-01 , 2.584e-01, 0.8],dtype=jnp.float64)
se = Model(data).get_se(x0)

hes [[ 5.00000000e+01 -4.06378551e-13  4.17754693e-14  0.00000000e+00]
 [-3.40315672e-13  1.23290937e+03 -6.83135224e+02  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 4.79170617e-14 -6.83135224e+02  8.59001000e+01  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]
```

I have `max()` here, could it be the problem?

When I use `Nelder-Mead` for minimization, `phi_hat` gets updated from callback. If I use `L-BFGS-B`, `phi_hat` stuck at the initial value. So could it be `L-BFGS-B` using jacobian for optimization but `Nelder-Mead` does not? and so I should not use autodiff or numerical differentiation to get hessian?

Update:
Drop the `max()` related part, now everything works.

Comment: If you define two variables whereby one of them is redundant or they are linearly dependent, then this issue might arise. Not sure how to help you as this seems not to be a programming question.

Comment: The column of 0 indicate that the variable is aliased to another. ie its linearly dependent on another

Comment: @Onyambu if it is the case, it would also cause convergence problem. Is this correct? Is A column of 0 more of the indication of linear dependence or redundant? Actually when I get rid of some parameters which seem most suspiciously dependent linearly, I still get a column of 0. Would this then be more of a sign of redundancy?

Comment: redundancy and linear dependence are interchangeable. Suppose you want to fit a curve/model on x and y and you define your equation as `y~a*(x-b) + c`. Note that b or c is redundant. ie this same equation can be expressed as `y~ax + b` ie an intercept and a slope. We know that we can only estimate these two parameters from a line, yet the equation has 3 variables. ie ill-defined. In the case of linear dependency, suppose you have data y,x1,x2 but x2 = a*x1+b, therefore the linear regression of y~x1+x2 will be ill defined as x2 is linearly dependent on x1. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're not computing the hessian, you're computing the outer product of the jacobian. An outer product of a vector with itself will always be singular.

Comment: it also gives singular matrix if I do `jax.hessian`.

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. I think the problem might lie in the use of `joblib` within a transformed JAX function: I would not expect that to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a column of zeros after replacing `joblib` with `for` loop. Can it be due to `max()` that I used?